# How do I add 'nofollow' link in java script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried in this way but it is not working:

```
Java Script:
<script type="text/javascript">

  function DoNav(theUrl)
  {
  document.location.href = theUrl;
  }
  </script>
Php code:
echo " onclick=\"DoNav('https://www.example.com/profile.php?id={$profile_id}'rel='nofollow');\">\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

nofollow concerns a classic link, not for a link opened on JS. It's for search engine robots.

```
// Will indicate a robot that it does not have to follow this link
<a href="http://www.link.com" rel="nofollow"></a> 

// If your action is JS opened you don't care to set nofollow, robots won't go on it.
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.link.com');"></a>
```

If you just want to prevent robot from accessing a particular adress on your website, you should use robots.txt : http://robots-txt.com/

If you just don't want google to access your particular page profile.php, You can ad this in robots.txt :

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: profile.php
```

And you can use classic links instead of JS ones, and add nofollow too :

```
<a href="./profile.php?id={$profile_id}" rel="nofollow">...</a>
```

You don't need to open it with JS

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Some  internal links of my page redirect to login page if already not  logged in. so I dont want to pass the link juice. Is this the process to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the link juice" ? pass to who ? What you really want to do ? prevent google to index a page of your site ?

Comment: Yest I don't want to pass hundreds of links to login page unnecessarily.

Comment: That I know, but I wanted in JS only. I think it is not possible.

Comment: Even if it was possible, nofollow has no meaning with window.open() or document.location.href =. It only affect classic links. If you really want you can do `echo " onclick=\"DoNav('https://www.example.com/profile.php?id={$profile_id});\" rel="nofollow">\n"; `